# Pycharm, Docker and GUI

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, x11

So i have downloaded openAI gym into docker. And i am running Pycharm with docker remote interpreter. Everything works fine until the code gets to the rendering part where it crashes. I know that it is caused because Docker does not support GUI.
I tried using x11 but it didnt work.
Any advice ?

Comment: Can you provide some example code and commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on OSX:
Your problem is probably not related with pycharm but more with how docker tries to connect to x11.

Make sure you installed the latest version of xQuartz and allow x11 network clients. Then mount the x11 socket as a volume mount in the docker container.

This blog post has a pretty good explanation on how to do that 
https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/

Comment: I am on linux (ubuntu), but i guess i can find xQuartz for linux.

Comment: @Anthony well no, xQuartz is an x11 specification for osx, if you're already on linux you can just use the x11 socket directly. you will still probably need to allow x11 network clients